# How do I link a domain name with Crazy Domains, to Heroku?

Tags: heroku, dns

I have managed to link a heroku app to dnssimple with the easy one click connect.  But how do i link the app to a domain on crazy domains?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to your Crazy Domains admin portal.
2. Click Domains tab and click on your domain name.
3. Under DNS Settings - Premium (Note I have to purchase premium DNS to activate forwarding as shown below), do something similar as below.

[CNAME Record]  www.censusplus.com.au   >   www.censusplus.com.au.herokudns.com

[Web Forward]       censusplus.com.au   >    www.censusplus.com.au

[Heroku]       www.censusplus.com.au    >   www.censusplus.com.au.herokudns.com

The above assumes you have already added your custom domain name in Heroku.

Comment: Thanks. I did as above but didn't have to do anything on heroku except for adding domain www.mydomain.whatever

It took around 15-30 minutes before all 3 of my browsers registered the change also.

Comment: @Engramar i try to create custom domain in heroku and give me a dns target and put the generated dns target on my crazy domains with cname record. but its not working. would you mind helping me? thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
$ heroku domains:add example.com
```

Comment: is that in the terminal?
and what settings do i change in crazy domains?
thanks!